# jQuery.get() not getting response from django http

Tags: jquery, django, httprequest

Odd - I can't seem to use a jQuery.get() to read the response from a django.HttpResponse.

From Django's end, I have a view:

```
def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world", content_type="application/html")
```

And URL:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
```

And when I visit http://localhost:8000/hello/, I see "Hello World" as expected.

In my webpage, though, I do this:

```
<html><head>
<script src="/asgapp/lib/jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#testdiv').html("initial");
      $.get('http://localhost:8000/hello/', function(data){
         if(data){
            $('#testdiv').html(data);
         }
         else{
            $('#testdiv').html("no data");
         }});
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>test page</h1>   
   <div id="testdiv">(empty)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In firebug, I see the request, but the response is empty, even though django has seen the request and processed the response.

Am I missing something?  Is this a jQuery issue or a django.HttpResponse thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a request to another domain like this (a different port falls under this), it's blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  It's not a jQuery or Django thing, it's how the browser implements security for the XmlHttpRequest object.

To make a request to another domain, you need to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) to pull the data.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize a port counted as a different domain!